# (node:14) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: ms is not defined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

As mentioned, I get the following error:

> (node:14) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: s is not
>   defined. I tried making a discord.js based bot, only the mute command
>   isn't working fine.

Checked multiple lines of code, replaced some with some, this error wasn't found in stackoverflow.

```
  await(tomute.addRole(muterole.id));

  setTimeout(function(){
    tomute.removeRole(muterole.id);
  }, ms(mutetime));
```

User should be muted for a specific time, but it doesn't unmute after the time rans out.

Comment: Remove ms(mutetime) and make it mutetime

Comment: did you require that package ? I mean did you do const ms = require('ms')

Comment: itsundefined, tried but the mute is Infinity, still same, Maksym Koldun, I will try and get back to you, thank you.

Comment: Seems like it worked, I forgot to require it, hahaha, it's a newbie mistake.